# How can I use a column's externalname as its refernce in a custom expression in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

because the column name will be dynamic in our analytic, we cannot do the standard custom expression syntax

```
[Amount]*2
```

we need to use something like this externalname which won't change (without notice anyway) like this.

```
{databaseTableName}.{Amount}.{ExternalName}*2
```

Doesn't have to be externalname but does have to bypass the dynamic column name.

Comment: what do you meant by " column name will be dynamic"? If you change a column name in an analysis, it's generally also updated in the expressions.  Who is changing it?

Comment: @MátéJuhász the column names are set via an IronPython script and can be changed by the client via the front end application.

Answer (score 0):

Keng, this sounds like an [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

it does not make sense to change the actual name of a column so frequently. what is your end goal? what added functionality are you providing by allowing this modification?

if you are trying to change the displayed name for a column, that is very easy to do with the `AS` keyword. `[MyColumn] AS [Some Column Name]` or `[Col_A] + [Col_B] AS [Sum of A and B]` or even `[Column] AS ${DocumentProperty}` will all provide a column with the given DISPLAY name without having to modify the underlying column at all.

Comment: the name change comes from the web app we have delivering the analytic to the customer.  we have one analytic that is getting delivered to n number of clients rather than having n number of analytics delivered to n number of clients (consider, for example, changing 300 analytics just to add another bar graph). The reason for that is that some clients want the column named "Associate" another wants it called "Cast Member" and we can allow that in general. Now it's a matter of calculated fields using external name (which doesn't change).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be to duplicate the column:

- keep it with its external name and refer to it in expressions
- create a calculated column just mirroring the original (`=[external name]`) and change its name with the script.